# How to write 2 digits after decimal point in C++?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point, double

In C language we can write like this;

```
printf("%.2f", number);
```

How can I do that in C++?

```
std::cout << "The number is " << number;
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip

Comment: [Check this example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/).

Comment: Should be a duplicate...

Answer (score 5):

You need to use the `iomanip` stuff, such as with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double pi = 3.141592653589;
    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << pi << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
3.14
```

If you want to localise the effects of your changes (both `fixed` and `setprecision` change the stream permanently), you can save the flags and precision before hand and restore them afterwards:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double pi = 3.141592653589;

    std::cout << pi << '\n';

    // Save flags/precision.
    std::ios_base::fmtflags oldflags = std::cout.flags();
    std::streamsize oldprecision = std::cout.precision();

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << pi << '\n';
    std::cout << pi << '\n';

    // Restore flags/precision.
    std::cout.flags (oldflags);
    std::cout.precision (oldprecision);

    std::cout << pi << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that is:

```
3.14159
3.14
3.14
3.14159
```

showing that the previous behaviour is being restored.

Comment: One thing to watch out for: `std::setprecision(2)` changes the state of `std::cout`, so it affects any later floating-point values you print.

Comment: @Keith, good point. Though it's probably not necessarily _directly_ applicable to this question, I'll mention it and provide a workaround.